# How to add .php extension using .htaccess url rewriting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have set up .htaccess file on my website which display SLUG text as page name in URL but without extension.
e.g. Real url is

```
www.mywebsite.com/page.php?page=about-us
```

Then it loads on below url through url rewriting

```
www.mywebsite.com/about-us
```

Below is my .htaccess file code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(images/|\.js|\.css).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /page.php?page=$1
```

Now I want to show the .php extension on all pages, so that the urls should be like below

```
www.mywebsite.com/about-us.php
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why would you want the .php extension. The url looks much cleaner without it. It's also better for SEO.

Comment: ya u r right but my seo is not understanding it. he wants pages with .php extension :P

Comment: Just tell him it will hurt his page ranking in search engines. Only slightly, but at least you are not lying to the man.

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(images/|\.js|\.css).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ /page.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Works okay on my test-server. Please recheck the code, as the change David made to your original should not cause a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

php_flag display_errors on
```