# How to add ".php" extension using ".htaccess"

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to add .php extension using .htaccess url rewriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799342/how-to-add-php-extension-using-htaccess-url-rewriting)

I want to add .php extension to url. using ."htaccess" How I can do it
my current URL is

```
http://www.abc
```

I want to change it as

```
http://www.abc.php
```

The content of .htaccess is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

And it is placed in root directory of my application
The question [already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799342/how-to-add-php-extension-using-htaccess-url-rewriting) but it is not working for me. I am using xampp server torun php

I do not know how to use htaccess. I want to know that

Comment: How does the urls looks like at the moment ?

Comment: in its simplest form: `RewriteRule thingsyouwant thingsyouwant.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: This is a exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8799342/508702

Comment: This question is not working for me

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman if that question is not answered it's most likely that yours won't be answered too, you can consider offering a [Bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: can you post what you have added to .htaccess ?

Comment: I do not know the actual method I want to know that

Comment: What? A TLD of `abc` and `php`?

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: open your .htaccess file and copy paste its contents here so that others can help.

Comment: I am not sure that there is not a bit of confusion – do you want to change what the web server reacts to, or do you want to rewrite what is going out?

Comment: @KonradNeuwirth I want to rewrite `somepage` to `somepage.php`

Comment: @mithunsatheesh I have pasted the contents of .htaccess file

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: comment all the lines by putting # at start of all lines and check op.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh nothing happened..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code rewrites all .html files to .php

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Comment: Sorry, I cant help anymore. Please give more explanatory about your problem.